# How to use sphinx to create pdf documentation?

Tags: pdf, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a folder containing rst files from which html documentation files are created using the following command:

```
sphinx-build -M html source build
```

I want to create a pdf file with the documentation instead, so I tried the following commands

```
sphinx-build -M pdf source build
sphinx-build -b pdf source build
sphinx-build -b pdf source build/pdf
```

but in any case I get the following error:

```
Sphinx error:
Builder name pdf not registered or available through entry point
```

I tried to google `"Builder name pdf not registered or available through entry point"` (with brackets) but got zero hits!

How to fix this error?

Comment: There is no pdf builder, but there are *latex builders from which a PDF may be generated. It's a two-step process: rst to latex to pdf. The *latex depends on your OS and what you may have installed. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/builders.html#sphinx.builders.latex.LaTeXBuilder

Comment: Thanks, I was able to create the latex. Now I seem I have to download a 2 GB large MacText package to create a pdf out of it. Or wait until tomorrow when I can use a sane OS (Ubuntu), which has it probably all built in!!!

Comment: Ain't macOS wunnerful? :P

Comment: @StevePiercy MacTeX also provides BasicTeX as alternative with bare minimals. BTW MacTeX is a slim wrapper of the TeXLive distribution. The size has **nothing at all** MacOS specific.

Comment: You can also use the [rinohtype PDF builder](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/quickstart.html#sphinx-builder) which is a small, pure-Python package.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out rinoh: https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype - works a treat. Not a pure laTex solution nor Sphinx, but it's quick and easy (and lightweight)!